# Make variable semi-readonly from some point on

Tags: c++, readonly

I want to ensure that a vector is unaltered after some point, so that I can safely work with pointers to the elements.

Of course I cannot make it const or readonly after a certain point and I don't want to define another variable which *is* const, because then the vector will get copied. Moreover, putting the initialization of the vector in a function which is called in the constructor (when the variable would be readonly) would make my code illogically structured.

Therefore I was hoping there would be a construct 'caged' along the following lines:

```
caged<Type> object;
object->change(); // underlying object changed
object.lock();
object->change(); // gives runtime error
const int data = object->getData(); // no problem
```

Is there such a construct?

How else could this be solved?

Comment: I don't see the illogical part of creating a `const vector` from a function...

Comment: You may create a const alias (a const reference) to avoid copy, but that doesn't prevent to use the *original* vector :-/

Comment: How about you simply don't pass it to any functions that could modify it? To be more explicit, only pass it to `const&` or `const*` functions.

Comment: I also do not see why instantiating a const in the constructor (via a dedicated function) would be illogical. As I understand, this is exactly the logic that you are asking for.

Comment: @Jarod42 The illogical part is not creating a const vector in a function, but calling the function in the constructor. First some functions get called which modify the object and then I want to freeze the object. I cannot put all these functions into the constructor; they are called after the object is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want to define another variable which is const, because then
>   the vector will get copied

Do not copy, but move your vector into this variable.

Raising runtime error on modification attempt is evil. Checking modification in compile time is the right way to go, and the only mechanism C++ has for it is `const`.

Initializing `const` variables with a function is the common approach. In fact, there is no much difference between initialization with a moved local vector or with a result of a function, which is also implicitly moved. As properly mentioned by @TartanLlama in the comments, copy may be (and usually is) completely elided in the latter case.

Comment: Note that when returning from a function the copy could be elided, which isn't the case in move-construction.

Comment: Still I perform a move. Moreover I am stuck with two variables: the const one and the non-const one. I want to freeze the object, not define another frozen object.

Comment: @Angelorf Moving vectors is extremely cheap. And why you cannot use initializing function, by the way? "Freezing" objects is a bad design. The beauty of `const` is that it is foolproof: compiler will check everything for your. I suppose that you need to expose more details bout your use case in order for community to be able to give you a more precise advice.

Comment: @Mikhail I have multiple places in the program where it occurs. For example when building up a mesh from a 3D file, the vertices are stored in a vector, which is reallocated as soon as it resizes. After the mesh has been built, we know that no resize will happen and so we use pointers to elements in the vector. I want to be able to *ensure* that no resize will happen, so that when I see a pointer to an element in a non-ensured vector I can figure out whether it is bug-happy code or not.

Comment: @Angelorf Sound easy. You just need to a) make array of vertices in your mesh immutable and b) provide a way to construct it. For a) encapsulate in some `Mesh` class, which simply does not provide interface to resize vector. For b) provide corresponding `Mesh` constructor.